# Momentjs current time is always 0

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

IM tring to format current time into format ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ, but the problem is the hours minutes and seconds  are always 00:00:00.

```
moment().format('ddd, DD, MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ');
```

Why is it always 0 and how can i get current time?

Comment: this still works with moment v2.27.0, could you provide more detail about the problem?

Comment: I run the code on nodejs with jest tests.

Comment: I would recommend checking if the correct momentjs is being used. I am able to get the current time using the exact same code you wrote.  Here is the example code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/moment-js-tu6npg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: What is the output of `node -e 'console.log(new Date());'`? Maybe the time cannot correctly be read by the system.

Comment: The problem is not coming from this code. Check other parts of your code.

Comment: new Date() gives everything. If i do moment().format() i get time.  But formatting the time with the custom format gives 00:00:00.

Comment: Got it working. Apparently in code it was yyyy that broke the thing, but here i wrote YYYY :D so yeah... i think im too tired.